# should i use sip and voip in Walkie-talkie app

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip

hello i have a project for client and he want to make a Walkie-talkie app on remote server that he have so should i use sip and VoIP because i searched for hours and i could,t find an answer for this question or there is an easier way to do  it and if i am going to do it i found a lib called pjsip but i could,t understand how to use it and should i build a VoIP server with it or use it alone and what is asterisk i know its a newbies questions but it my first time to develop an app using VoIP or sip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIP/VoIP just an protocol to connect between parties & parties connect through server which is known as Registrar/Proxy Server.
After connection is done, it now goes to RTP protocol to actual media exchange.

So nowdays PJSIP is popular SIP stack which can be used to communicate. Asterisk is also know an Proxy/REgistrar server .

Yes you can use PJSIP with Asterisk, but asterisk is little complicated in understanding( config) ,  you can start with something easier also

Answer (score 0):

I've made an app like this and yes, it would be best suitable for your app.

From my experience, I used `Freeswitch` SIP server client on Debian8 (https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie).

and I used `linphone` for VoIP client library (https://www.linphone.org/).

They are both amazing and well maintained.

linphone is a cross-platform library so you can easily write apps for mobile (Android, iOS, and Windows Phone), PC, OSX, and Linux.

Good luck!